# method is calling recursively though parameters are different?

Tags: java, reflection

I have below methods.It is giving **StackoverflowError**. Any reason?

### SomeClass.java

```
public static <T extends BaseClass> T newObject(Class<T> classOfT, Emp data) {

        return newObject(classOfT, data);
    }
```

newObject method implementation

```
 private static <T extends BaseClass> T newObject(Class<T> classOfT, Object data) {

            //some logic and return subclass instance of BaseClass
        }
```

Here newObject method is being called recursively. But why is not calling private newObject method?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a stopping condition? If not it's just going to recurse infinitely (until it breaks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
public static <T extends BaseClass> T newObject(Class<T> classOfT, Emp data) {

        return newObject(classOfT, (Object)data);
    }
```

`Uppercast` your second argument to `Object` type. This will make the appropriate call to the private method which suits the method signature

Answer (score 1):

This is called [**Finding the most specific method**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). Compiler starts searching for appropriate method from the bottom of class hierarchy. `Emp` is a child of Object, that's why public method is the most specific one, becouse signatures differ only in the second parameter.

Comment: Mikhail, could you please suggest me any alternative? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you rename second private method. I think overloading should be avoided where possible. The only thing, where its useful are constructors.